# How do I stop people being able to see every file in my Amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud

If someone goes to the url of my bucket, they are able to see every single file listed.

Although I want the files in my bucket to be able to be seen by the public, I'd prefer not to have this list view available. Is there a way to prevent "directory listings" like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should remove read access for "All Users" built-in group from the bucket's ACL. You can do that using the tool like [CloudBerry Explorer freeware](http://s3.cloudberrylab.com/)
Make sure you keep read access on the files you want to serve from S3.

Thanks
Andy